# stripping ,(commas) from text in msaccess query

Tags: ms-access

Can someone please advise how i can create an expression for use in a msaccess query, that strips out , and . characters and replaces them with a space

for example i have a data field containing customer names (eg Mickey Mouse Company, Ltd.)

i need to extract this from the database using a query, and export it to csv file, but as you can imagine the , in the customer name creates problems in the csv file

will it possible to creat an expression to strip these punctuation marks out and replace them with a space so that the subsequent csv file doesnt get messed up

many thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use the [`replace`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/replace.php) function.  Syntax is like *string*, *find*, *replace*, so something like this (if you're using the query designer):

```
field_name: replace([field_name], ",", " ")
```